# Is this type of conditional sentence used by native speakers?

Tags: conditionals, descriptive-grammar, conditional-perfect

I was wondering if any native speaker uses the following type of conditional sentence:

> If my mother-in-law **was coming** tomorrow, I **would have spent**
>   all day cleaning the house.

The sentence appears in *Conditionals: A Comprehensive Empirical Analysis*, by Renaat Declerck, Susan Reed (2001). The book says the sentence is counterfactual.

([Link to sentence in book] (https://books.google.com/books?id=RtyewWWe1LAC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq="If+my+mother-in-law+was+coming++tomorrow,+I+would+have+spent+all+day+cleaning+the+house"))

Comment: As opposed to....what? Are you asking about the simple past tense in the "if" clause? Careful writers might prefer the plural form *were* in place of *was*. I believe that this type of conditional is very common among British English speakers. Are you troubled about the tense used in the second half of the sentence? What exactly is bothering you?

Comment: I am not comfortable with that. For a future proposition/possibility, I would write/say, If my m-i-l came tomorrow, I would spend all day cleaning the house. Alternatively, floating the predicate into retrospective past: If my m-i-l were coming the next day, I would have spent all day cleaning the house.

Comment: I'm really confused about using the past continuous with the adverb "tomorrow" in the first part and the combination"would have spent" in the second part. Isn't it odd?

Comment: @mido mido No, it's wrong; the conditional _if_ - clause is referring to a future event (her arrival tomorrow), and hence is inconsistent with the use of would+ present perfect which has a past time meaning. Better to say _If my mother-in-law was coming tomorrow, I would spend all day cleaning the house_ . Alternatively, if you want to retain a past time meaning throughout, you could say _If I had known my mother-in-law was coming tomorrow, I would have spent all day cleaning the house_.

Comment: @Bill J: You're right. Your first version with "would spend" sounds natural.

Comment: **Yes.** I'm a native speaker and this kind of conditional phrasing is exactly what I would use.

Comment: Please clarify your question, comments are not always read by users, and so your question risks being misunderstood, the problem seems centred on the usage of past continuous and present perfect.

Comment: @BillJ Isn't *would spend all day*  innapropriate if you're talking at 11 pm?

Comment: Yes, that’s true. But looked at that way, any answer to the OP’s question would have to be qualified each time with the proviso that the acceptability of their example depends on the time of day of the utterance, thus okay to say it late in the day, but probably inappropriate to say it early in the day. Which is why I corrected it to the form of a kind of idiom, a fixed phrase almost, usable at any time, meaning that **in general** one would be likely to spend a lot of time, perhaps all day, cleaning the house if one’s mother-in-law was coming the following day!  Opinions will vary, no doubt.

Comment: Someone has gone through the answers and downvoted all of them. I would just love to know why mine was downvoted. :) It was completely straightforward!!

Comment: The authors clearly state that the book is based on English corpora. Why, then, do you ask if English speakers actually say such things?

Comment: Corpora is written text. That's why. And the question was: I was wondering if any ***native speaker uses the following type of conditional sentence***.

Answer (score 3):

> If my mother-in-law was coming tomorrow, I would have spent all day cleaning the house.

This sentence is actually grammatical, but very specifically conveys as a matter of fact that if your mother-in-law had decided to come tomorrow, then you would have spent all day cleaning the house. But you did not, because she had not decided to come tomorrow. This is an instance of the common usage of the past continuous tense for a past decision to do something (which may be in the future), but non-native speakers are very often unaware of it. Another example is "If he was coming tomorrow, he would have told us.", and changing "was coming" to "is coming" would make it sound weird to a native speaker!

> If my mother-in-law were coming tomorrow, I would have spent all day cleaning the house.

This is also valid with pretty much the same meaning, but less commonly used even by native speakers today. Both of these are indeed counterfactual, because the "would have spent" implies that you actually did not spend all day cleaning the house.

> If my mother-in-law is coming tomorrow, I would spend all day cleaning the house.

This has a different meaning, and merely states how you would respond to a hypothetical situation and does not state whether or not the situation will happen. Note that the present tense of "is coming" is never used for the counterfactual, so it would be incorrect to replace "would spend" with "would have spent".

Comment: @Clare: In the universe with human mistakes. I hope it is obvious that it was a slip, not that I don't know proper grammar. I also don't understand how I made the error, which I will of course fix now.

Comment: +1 An example of how the original sentence might be used: "Your in-laws are arriving tomorrow morning, and you spent the day at the beach!? **If *my* mother-in-law was coming tomorrow, I would have spent all day cleaning the house**!"

Comment: It actually is not grammatical: If my MIL was coming, I would be spending all day cleaning. I rarely hear an IF clause in the past continuous followed by a second clause in the past conditional. For example:  **If he were leaving tomorrow, I would have gone already.*** That's another one and it makes zero sense. Of all the non-standard patterns one hears, this is simply not one of them.

Comment: +1 after the fix. Your interpretation also fits that of the text from which the sentence is taken.

Comment: @Clare: Thank you! Unfortunately, Google Books tells me that the page is unavailable for viewing or I have reached the limit for the book.

Comment: @Lambie: Your version is fine if there is still much of the day left (for cleaning). However, if the day has already mostly gone by, then it is in fact necessary to use "would have spent" rather than "would be spending", and an example has been provided by *1006a*. As I've explained in my answer this construction has a very specific meaning. Did you consider the other example I had given? "If he was coming tomorrow, he would have told us (by now)." is correct for this reason, and "would be telling" conveys the wrong meaning.

Comment: @user21820 If he was coming tomorrow [which he isn't], he would tell us. If he **had** come [which he also didn't], he would have told us. Or: If he had been coming [which he wasn't], he would have told us. [the most "correct"]. It is simply not standard the way you say it.

Comment: @Lambie: I am a native speaker and your notion of "standard English" is simply not congruent with my native tongue. The 'tense' of the two parts are not tied together but depends on the specific semantics desired for each part. Twice now you have avoided addressing the example I have given you: **"If he was coming tomorrow, he would have told us by now."** There is no other correct choice of tenses to convey this particular meaning.

Comment: @user21820 Not congruent with your native tongue? Hm. Strike me dead. :) OK, this sentence of  yours and the OP's: "If he was coming tomorrow, he would have told us by now." may be said, people do say that kind of thing. But "technically", it is not standard. standard is: If he was coming tomorrow, he would tell us. It is NOT standard to use the IF + past continuous subjunctive with would + have+ verb (past conditional) in the second clause. Now, if you taught English, you would know this. Apparently you haven't. Standard is: If he had been coming, he would have told us by now.

Comment: What I have said in my answer and here is born out by all English grammar sites both AmE and BrE. You can go and check them: If-clauses, three kinds, plus mixed conditionals.

Comment: @Lambie: I'm inclined towards descriptivism. Since you agree that people do say the kind of sentence that I've given, then it is clearly grammatical to them. Now, one could ask whether it is a minority who do this. I do not believe so, and a quick Google search lends some (weak) evidence to my claim. For instance, you insisted that if the apodosis has "X would have done Y" then the protasis must be "if P had been Q" rather than "if P was Q". That is totally wrong when the past tense is used to convey intention rather than temporal semantics, as I have explained in my answer. [continued]

Comment: @Lambie: You keep changing my sentence as well, in order to protect your claim. I purposely added the phrase "by now", which you would be unable to convey in your form because "would tell us by now" is simply incorrect. Likewise "had been coming tomorrow" is incorrect, whereas "was coming tomorrow" can be used with the specific meaning of "was intending to come tomorrow". Even if you are a prescriptivist, you will have to deal with this semantics separately from the usual rules. And just for laughs, if we want to be pedantic, "Hm" is not standard English. =)

Comment: user21828 Absolutely not. People speak as they speak, which is fine, and as a linguist I am interested in all speech, but if they are not educated, they are usually completely clueless about their own speech. That's even true of supposedly educated speakers: in AmE right now, would/would is everywhere (even with "college educated" speakers) and present perfect/conditional with irregular verbs are fast disappearing. Some talking head surrogate on CNN keeps saying things like: we have began or they have not did it yet. The problem in complex utterances is really one of "power".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59181/discussion-between-user21820-and-lambie).

Answer (score -1):

A counterfactual sentence is a condition contrary to fact:
Here's the actual "standard" grammar:

1) If I go, I will see him. Present (either form) + Future with Will OR
If I am going, I will see him.

2) If I went, I would see him. Simple Past Tense + Present Conditional
HERE's the KICKER:

3) If I had gone, I would have seen him. Pluperfect + Past Conditional

The difference between 1) and 2) is how much you want to emphasize the probability. 1) is just an IF statement. 2) is a contrafactual.

Now, your sentence: /If my mother-in-law was coming tomorrow, I would have spent all day cleaning the house./ is agrammatical in English.

It should be:If my mother-in-law was [or were] coming tomorrow, I would spend all day cleaning the house. That makes it a type 1) sentence. To make it type 2): If my mother-in-law had been coming yesterday,I would have spent all day cleaning the  house.

Comment: Show your face, downvoter. My answer is a 100% standard take on this issue.

Comment: First, the question is not whether the sentence is "standard grammar". Next, there are many more types of conditionals than three. Third, the sentence seemed fine to my intuition. Fourth, the sentence comes straight out of a study of the English conditional which is based on actual corpora, and the text is "data-driven" (authors' words). I believe that's called descriptive grammar. Trying to judge every actual conditional utterance into some kind of artificial schema that includes a very small number of "standard constructions" does not seem to me to  be the way to go here.

Comment: All this stuff about corpora is mostly nonsense since, strictly speaking, ***corpora refers to written text***. Data-driven, my foot. Descriptive grammar does deal with how people speak so the "corpora" has to come from recorded media. The sentence is not even a good non-standard sentence where the tendency is: would/would have. And not: was + ing/would have PP. The sentence is therefore untenable as it makes no sense. The question was about NATIVE speakers. And the typical native speaker heard in the media etc. tends toward WOULD/WOULD HAVE. for contrefactuals.

Comment: And for the second clause If she was coming tomorrow, I would be spending all day cleaning. Not: would have spent.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I put the word standard in quotation marks. One has to be able to work off of or in relation to something.

Answer (score -1):

As a native speaker, I generally use a version of the subjunctive mood for this.

> If my mother in law **were coming** tomorrow, I would have spent all day cleaning the house.

This isn't a conscious decision, but I suppose that I have chosen this construction because the mother-in-law's visit is not factual, but hypothetical. When discussing hypothetical situations, and one's response or differing experience in response to that situation, I generally use the subjunctive.

It is also worth noting that there is only one verb with a specific past-subjunctive form: *be* is the present form, which becomes *were*.

This may not be a very standard usage of this mood, but you asked about native speakers, so descriptivism is all we can offer.